# Excluding a single key from an object type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to write typings for a color converter. Everything works in JS because in a condition I made sure no wrong converter method will be called. TS does not know how to infer the fact that the problematic option has been ruled out. I get

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'OutputFormat' can't be used to index type '{ hsl: () => string; hsv: () => string; } | { rgb: () => string; hsv: () => string; } | { rgb: () => string; hsl: () => string; }'.
  Property 'rgb' does not exist on type '{ hsl: () => string; hsv: () => string; } | { rgb: () => string; hsv: () => string; } | { rgb: () => string; hsl: () => string; }'.
```

Unfortunately, utils like `Exclude<T,U>` do not work here because they operate on whole unions whereas I'd like to tell TS that `from` in `const from = converters[ inputFormat ];` will never have `outputFormat` as a key.

How do I work around this thing?

[The live sanbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8grsMCBiB7ATgWwIbCgXigHJ0BzAIyKgB9iALAZwBsrajGA3IgbgCheA9AKgAVOgEsGUSVGzpy44OjkgANFDDpUHcQBMIuqORCyAdlAgAPYBHSnsTKE3Hll6EADpeAY1SmGeL6mHLY26FKEAN68AJBCUAByqDZQwHS4qXS20DKmqFBk5FAA1hAmWegQXjGFAFxQ0TExjEz1ABQAlPUB6OKmpAQAfMQAZqioRKqxzQwc7V1QPX0D%20MNEYxNTMQC%20W-FJKWkZadnSUnlQLSVll9nVLfWNNRTz3UrLQ6Pjk9Ocr4vvfqfdbfLa7WL7ZLQI54E6VM5QC6ca7lO6xP4NaZ1KCdN69IGrL6bX7Mf5LAlrDZEWLbXjbPi8EZwUzeYDiPxQIIhdDANqc1BMDB45bqVAIJDANBYXD1eCIFAYHB4BbkgaNIIBaSmCVSpUEKD6Gys3W4Pm%20QXoKAdBkxcQjHFanWKjL4V1QMXyyXO5WYpqVYBwOz8i18Hb8GIavAjLSYfVc0K2BgAbUdCuleAAujb4vGeYmPIUCxROu7LbmwgwPC0q8wSwB3cRMRymCDcy7YMCQczkCDebBwBjQVD2k4Q4RBXSKdnmY5ZIwQUh9UwfYeZaCYCBpVC6DxQABCCFEAGUDagIOdkiU8nXMrhqpHUvlCNHUJgUx6nemoFnw-7A%20ZgFQM0BQwK0%20FpRlmVZacDU3XsvXTYCLWFIEFhIChWHoZhMPYWYqEaP8g3QyhwO4IA) for the code below

```
type OutputFormat = 'rgb' | 'hsl' | 'hsv';

// This is arbitrary, provided by an external library.
const converters = {
    // Note that there is no rgb key here.
    rgb: {
        hsl: (): string => 'foo',
        hsv: (): string => 'foo',
    },
    // Note that there is no hsl key here.
    hsl: {
        rgb: (): string => 'foo',
        hsv: (): string => 'foo',
    },
    // Note that there is no hsv key here.
    hsv: {
        rgb: (): string => 'foo',
        hsl: (): string => 'foo'
    }
};

function convert( color: string, outputFormat: OutputFormat ): string {
    const inputFormat = detectFormat( color );

    if ( inputFormat === outputFormat ) {
        return color;
    }

    const from = converters[ inputFormat ];

    // converters.rgb.rgb() or converters.hsl.hsl() will never happen because of the
    // condition at the beginning of the method. But TS does not know that.
    const to = from[ outputFormat ];

    return to( color );
}

function detectFormat( color: string ): 'rgb' | 'hsl' | 'hsv' {
    return 'rgb';
};
```

Comment: It's almost certainly not worth trying to get the compiler to understand the relationship here; you can always just assert your way out with `from[outputFormat as never] as (x: string) => string`, but I'd say it's better to refactor to something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w6pj0m) where the compiler generally understands that `from[i][o]` is either a function or undefined and to check that.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm unable to change types for `const convert`. [They are provided by the community](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/color-convert/index.d.ts). For the record, the library I'm using is https://www.npmjs.com/package/color-convert.

Comment: Do you mean `converters`?  If so then I'm confused, since you don't need to change the type of the original `const` to get the same behavior, you just need to assign to a variable of the right type, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoY9lN), for example.  Surely you are able to do that, right?  If not, then can you [edit] to lay out exactly what you're allowed to do?

Comment: `const converters` comes from an external library and has own types. They are complex: every sub-object in `const converters` has ~20 methods. Each method has specific input and output. There are 20 keys. It's a library for converting from any color space to any color space. I cannot override these types, I must accept them as they come.

Comment: And in [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/WoY9lN) I accepted your type as it came, but then reassigned to a new variable. If that doesn't work for you, you should probably [edit] the code example to demonstrate why. With such an example I could possibly show how to write a type function to transform `typeof converters` into a more palatable type regardless if it has 20 or 200 methods... but *without* a [mre] I couldn't guess what the function looks like.  Anyway I'll disengage unless I see an [edit] where that happens. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
function convert( color: string, outputFormat: OutputFormat ): string {
    const inputFormat = detectFormat( color );

    if ( inputFormat === outputFormat ) {
        return color;
    }

    const from = converters[ inputFormat ];

    // converters.rgb.rgb() or converters.hsl.hsl() will never happen because of the
    // condition at the beginning of the method. But TS does not know that.
    return Object.entries(from).filter(([key,_]) => key === outputFormat).map(([_, value]) => value())[0];
}
```